# Break java string into array of all words and all possible consecutive two word combinations

Tags: java, string

I need to take a sentence string and break it up into an array that contains each word in the string as well as each combination of consecutive words. 
So "the dog runs fast" will turn into

```
the
dog
runs
fast
the dog
dog runs
runs fast
```

I know I can obtain the one word tokens using String.split("\s") and the two word tokens rather easily by iterating through the string and adding them one at a time, but I'm working with a lot of strings that are all fairly long and this method is simply too slow. Is there some kind of built in or regex solution to this? Thanks

Comment: `String.split("\\s")` *is* the regex solution.  I think you'll need to write a custom parser if want this to be much faster.

Comment: regex?? it will make it even slow.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: @markspace String.split("\\s") only creates Array(see, the, fast, dog, run), not the combinations

Answer (score 1):

StringTokenizer is quite a bit faster than String.split(), see the comparison below:

http://demeranville.com/battle-of-the-tokenizers-delimited-text-parser-performance/

You can see how it improves your overall performance. Splitting all the words and building 2-grams from a long text is going to take some time anyway.